# what does below cron expression ,means?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

i have below cron expression.

```
"0 0 0 ? * SUN"
```

when exactly this is executed? midnight of sunday of saturday?

Thanks!

Comment: +1: It appears simple, but appears to use undefined behaviour.

Comment: http://dev6.axeda.com/help/en/cron_expression_fields.htm

Comment: Its not a cron expression but a quartz expression which is similar but different (and has one more field)

Comment: @wuppi quartz is a Java library for scheduling (based on cron)

Comment: oh ok. thanks. learned something today :)

Answer (score 23):

See the [tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06)

```
*   *    *    *    *    *   (year optional)
┬   ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│   │    │    │    │    │
│   │    │    │    │    │
│   │    │    │    │    └───── day of week (0 - 7) (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)
│   │    │    │    └────────── month (1 - 12)
│   │    │    └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│   │    └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
│   └───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
└─────────────────────────      seconds
```

Wild-cards (the * character) can be used to say "every" possible value of this field. Therefore the * character in the "Month" field of the previous example simply means "every month". A '*' in the Day-Of-Week field would therefore obviously mean "every day of the week".

The '?' character is allowed for the day-of-month and day-of-week fields. It is used to specify "no specific value". This is useful when you need to specify something in one of the two fields, but not the other. See the examples below (and CronTrigger JavaDoc) for clarification.

So it means every sunday at midnight

Comment: He's based on [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger). It has a cron expression with seconds, not like the bas cron expression

Answer (score 4):

This is not actually a cron expression. It is a quartz-schedule expression.

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/crontrigger

The `0 0 0` means midnight (second, minutes, hour)

The `?` means it depends on other fields.

The `*` means all months.

The `SUN` means on Sunday.

Comment: He's talking about Quartz Cron Trigger, which is slightly different from Cron expressions :See this example from quartz doc :
0 15 10 ? * MON-FRI Fire at 10:15am every Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday

Answer (score 1):

The trigger will fire at 00:00:00 AM On every sunday (morning). 0 is the beginning of a day, not the end. So it will fire the next second to 23:59:59 on Saturday